# Get category on topic id

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to get the category name to be showed on the id of the topic.
Currently i have this

```
        $cato = $db->prepare('SELECT
                        topics.topic_cat,
                        topics.topic_id,
                        categories.cat_id,
                        categories.cat_name
                    FROM
                        topics
                    LEFT JOIN
                        categories
                    ON
                        topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
                    WHERE
                        topics.topic_id =:topid');

$cato->bindParam(':topid',  $row2["topic_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$cato->execute();
$result2 = $cato->fetch();
```

`Categories.cat_id` is the id of the category.

`Categories.cat_name` is the name i want get.

`Topics.topic_cat` is the category id where the topic is posted ( the same id from categories.cat_id)

`Topics.topic_id` is the id of the topic (`topic.php?id=28`)

My result needs to be

topic 28 is in category hello (hello = `categories.cat_name`).

So, to be short: the topic id is 28 it searches in topics the row with `topic_id` 28 and grabs the topic_cat that is in the same row as `topic_id` 28. Then it looks in categories and grabs the `categories_name` is `topic_cat`. then it posts the `categories_name`

I hope i am clear enough.

Comment: Do you have uncategorized topics?

Comment: @makciook only in the index its showing all if u mean that?

Comment: i'm asking why do you `LEFT JOIN` to the categories table and not just `JOIN`? It means there exist topics you want to list that are not given category ids.

Comment: @makciook to be fear. i have no idea. with other scripts left join worked :x sounds stupid i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
SELECT topics.topic_cat,
       topics.topic_id,
       categories.cat_id,
       categories.cat_name
FROM topics, categories
WHERE topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
      AND topics.topic_id =:topid
```

This should work unless you have topic without category.

Comment: And how do i display the result (sorry for my noobie question)

Comment: Based on your code, you can do `$result2 = $cato->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` then to get category name, you have `echo $result2['cat_name']`. If you are not sure about that, then `print_r($result2)` to debug.

Comment: Getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in `

on line `$result2 = $cato->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: So it means the query is failed, could you debug the above query in a tool like phpmyadmin?

Comment: its working! only needed to change the `:topid` to the variable  `$row2["topic_id"]` 

Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes I only tried to replace the query part of your above code. So please keep `:topicid` and `bindParam()` part to prevent SQL injection and you are good to go.